# How to add a new sheet to an existing xls using spreadsheet in ruby

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet

I have used spreadsheet gem to update my xls with test result but now I want to store result of multiple tests in form of sheets in a single xls. But when using write function in spreadsheet, it overwrites the older sheet.

Plz help me with a solution or any alternative if available, Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Show ur code please.

Comment: I have used axlsx gem to generate multi-sheet files. Only generates .xlsx files, though, not the legacy .xls